# FileReader file not found Mac

Tags: java

I'm trying to use FileReader on Mac. I've created a FileReader as:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("~\\Documents\\workspace\\ProjectAMChart\\amcharts_3.11.1.free\\amcharts\\amcharts.js");
```

But for some reason, I always get a `FileNotFoundException`. How am I supposed to enter the proper file path on a Mac?

Comment: Try to use the absolute path!

Comment: So how would I enter that? I know I need the path, but what exactly do I type between the quotation marks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Use forward slashes on a Mac.  In fact, always use forward slashes, the system should take care of substituting the correct delimiter, even on Windows.
2. `~` is a shell metacharacter. Use the `user.home` system property instead.

i.e.

```
String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(
    userHome + 
    "/Documents/workspace/ProjectAMChart/amcharts_3.11.1.free/amcharts/amcharts.js");
```

Comment: Typo: I think you mean `System.getProperty("user.home")` instead of `System.getProperty("path.separator")`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using single forward slashes not double backslashes.

```
EX: "/Documents/workspace/ProjectAMChart/amcharts_3.11.1.free/amcharts/amcharts.js"
```

Comment: Guy above me just beat me to it!